# How many elements in quotient ring satisfies $\alpha^4 = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $I$ be the ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ generated by the polynomial $x^3 − 8$. Consider the quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/I$. Find the number of elements $\alpha$ of the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/I$ satisfying $\alpha^4−1 = 0$

I assume the $1$ here refers to the set $\langle x^3 - 8 \rangle+1$ and I am completely lost. I just started learning commutative algebra.

I know that every element in the quotient ring can be written as $ax^2 + bx + c + \langle x^3 - 8\rangle$. Multiply the quadratic four times and divide by $x^3 - 8$ seems extremely difficult. I also noticed (without proof) that the quotient ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, but that did not help. Finally, I know that $x^3 - 8 = (x - 2)(x^2 +2x + 4)$, but not sure how to proceed? I feel that is the right way to go.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb R[X]/I\simeq\mathbb R\times\mathbb C$.

Comment: The direct approach is to take an arbitrary element $ax^2+bx+c+ I$, cube it, find a second-degree representative, and solve the equations you get for $a,b,c$. I don't know how hard that really is.

Comment: The fact that the OP hasn't put any context in the question means that we don't know what sort of hint to supply you with. Do you understand @user26857's hint, for example? If so, it's a great hint.

Comment: @GregMartin I just started learning the subject.. Does it has something to do with $x^3 - 8 = (x-2)(x^2 + 2x + 4)$?

Comment: @GregMartin Oh... I just started reading about CRT. Is it that? So in the end  we just consider how to make $(x, y+ zi)^4 = (1,1)$?

Comment: Yes. Note that the question asks you to count the number of solutions; and counting the number of solutions is often easier than finding them.

Comment: @GregMartin I see. So in the end the answer is just $2\times 4 = 8$. I was lost because I didn't learn about CRT....

Comment: Trying to solve a problem, thinking hard, getting stuck, suddenly seeing how to get unstuck, finishing the problem—that *is* learning!